# Create file in TFTP server

Tags: file-io, tftp

I have a requirement like this. Log files has to be created in TFTP server in Ubuntu. I am using this TFTP version (tftp-hpa 0.49).

The only problem here is, the log file which i am dumping into the TFTP server has to be present already. If the file is not present already, i am unable to create the log file. My requirement is to create log files dynamically in TFTP server.

Please let me know, is there any way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

edit

/etc/default/tftpd-hpa

adding the option **--create** to the variable **TFTP_OPTIONS**=

**--create**:
Allow new files to be created. By default, tftpd will only allow upload of files that
already exist. Files are created with default permissions allowing anyone to read or write 
them, unless the --permissive or --umask options are specified.